# How to find if user relation exists on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called users and another table called relationship which has a column of two userId. I want to find an output if the user has a relationship with another user, (for this example, it is a user with userId = 2). If they do have a relationship, I want my output to be true, else false. I am having some trouble and wondering if anyone can help me.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        userid,
        CASE WHEN user_one_id = '2' THEN true ELSE false END AS has_user_two 
FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN relationship ON userid = user_two_id;
```

However, I am getting duplicates...

My Query output that is wrong

```
userid  | has_user_two| 
---------------------+
1       | true        | 
1       | false       | 
2       | false       | 
3       | false       | 
4       | true        | 
5       | true        |
```

Users

```
   userid
-----------
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

relationship

```
user_one_id| user_two_id
-----------+-------------
 1         | 1
 3         | 1
 3         | 2
```

My output should look something like...

```
userid  | has_user_two| 
---------------------+
1       | true        | 
2       | false       | 
3       | false       | 
4       | false       | 
5       | false       |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `CASE WHEN user_one_id = '2' THEN true ELSE false END AS has_user_two` can be simplified to `user_one_id = '2' as has_user_two`

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.userid,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM relationship r
                WHERE r.user_one_id = 2 AND r.user_two_id = u.userid
               )
       ) as has_user_two
FROM users u;
```

Note that you don't need a `CASE` expression in Postgres.  A boolean expression can be -- well -- a boolean column.